# How do I import my project into a Playground in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode10

Luckily in Xcode 10 you can once again create a Playground inside of an Xcode project. I'm able to import my pods but I'd like to import my classes for quick Playground-driven development. My project is called `foo` but I'm not able to do `import foo` in the Playground. The playground is located in `Foo/foo` in the directory structure.